# Can't start PowerShell 3.0 on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm having a very strange issue where powershell seems to hang on startup, but only on version 3:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powershell -version 2.0
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> exit

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powershell -version 3.0
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

_ (blinking cursor here)
```

If I press ctrl-break then powershell crashes. The windows error report shows an exception in Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.BreakIntoDebugger, so that might be related. I can't find any information about reinstalling powershell on windows 10 so I'm not sure how to proceed. Adding and removing powershell 2 from programs and features didn't help, and neither has rebooting. I have also tried `powershell -noprofile` with the same result. I have also tried `powershell -Command {echo "test"}` and it hangs forever and I am unable to ctrl-break.

WER:

```
Version=1
EventType=PowerShell
EventTime=131305552298905352
ReportType=1
Consent=1
UploadTime=131305552299996306
ReportIdentifier=7f7872e4-e9a7-11e6-8287-6245b4ec6498
AppSessionGuid=00002eac-0001-000f-73e4-9681b37dd201
TargetAppId=W:0000f519feec486de87ed73cb92d3cac802400000000!0000044a0cf1f6bc478a7172bf207eef1e201a18ba02!powershell.exe
TargetAppVer=2016//09//15:16:31:49!789c3!powershell.exe
BootId=4294967295
Response.BucketId=c8f5b6fc0a27bdd03326cfefd2006eb7
Response.BucketTable=5
Response.LegacyBucketId=127762705495
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=NameOfExe
Sig[0].Value=powershell.exe
Sig[1].Name=FileVersionOfSystemManagementAutomation
Sig[1].Value=10.0.14393.693
Sig[2].Name=InnermostExceptionType
Sig[2].Value=System.NullReferenceException
Sig[3].Name=OutermostExceptionType
Sig[3].Value=System.NullReferenceException
Sig[4].Name=DeepestPowerShellFrame
Sig[4].Value=Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.BreakIntoDebugger
Sig[5].Name=DeepestFrame
Sig[5].Value=Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.BreakIntoDebugger
Sig[6].Name=ThreadName
Sig[6].Value=unknown
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.14393.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=3081
UI[3]=powershell has stopped working
UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
UI[5]=Check online for a solution and close the program
UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program
UI[7]=Close the program
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
FriendlyEventName=PowerShell
ConsentKey=PowerShell
AppName=powershell
AppPath=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
ApplicationIdentity=00000000000000000000000000000000
MetadataHash=-149969992
```

Output of DISM repair:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Image Version: 10.0.14393.0

No component store corruption detected.
The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: You post the results of the DISM command that repairs your system health?

Comment: Does adding the `-noprofile` switch help?

Comment: `-noprofile` didn't help. I've updated the question, thanks @BenN

Comment: @Ramhound updated with DISM repair info. I've also tried SFC and there weren't any problems. The only other thing I can think of is that I'm on a domain account but the domain controller is currently unavailable. I will login as a local user and see if that helps.

Comment: Hmm turns out that this seems to be a problem with my antivirus (AVG). disabling it fixes powershell, and it keeps working even after i reenable it. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been a problem with my antivirus scanner (AVG). Disabling it fixes the problem, and powershell continues to work once I re-enable the antivirus.